# .npz file contains sparse matrices. But it is not possible to read these matrices. How to fix this problem?

Tags: numpy, sparse-matrix

`54.npz` contains 5 sparse matrices. But when I load this `54.npz` it's not possible to read sparse matrices.

```
data = np.load('54.npz', mmap_mode='r')
print(data.files)
['arr_0', 'arr_1', 'arr_2', 'arr_3', 'arr_4']
```

Now if we try to print one of the `arr_i` it doesn't print matrix.

```
B=data['arr_0']
print(B)
B.view()

Output:
B
array('B', dtype='<U1')
```

Actually, when we print matrix B, output should be like this:

```
B=np.load('B.npy', allow_pickle=True)
print(B)
B.view()

Output:

(0, 0)  1.0
(1, 1)  1.0
...
(6681, 8583)    4.0
(8581, 8583)    8.0
array(<8584x8584 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'with 11185 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>, dtype=object)
```

Here is a link for `.npz` file https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vawZtvQifR_3PZHhxFbZnB7yb-Lnf6oC?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You just save 5 letters:

```
In [243]: data = np.load('54.npz')
In [244]: data
Out[244]: <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile at 0x7fa873bb3c10>
In [245]: data['arr_0']
Out[245]: array('B', dtype='<U1')
In [246]: data['arr_1']
Out[246]: array('P', dtype='<U1')
In [247]: data['arr_2']
Out[247]: array('L', dtype='<U1')
In [248]: data['arr_3']
Out[248]: array('U', dtype='<U1')
In [249]: data['arr_4']
Out[249]: array('Q', dtype='<U1')
```

There's no sparse matrices in that archive.

Without knowing how you created the file we can't help you!

Comment: Actually, this .npz file wasn't saved by me. Please, could you extract this .npz file or watch using Total Commander. Then you will see .npy files. If you load the .npy file then you see a sparse matrix. But this solution to the problem is very slow. There are a lot of .npz files.